# Solution to equations involving Plasma dispersion function

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, special-functions

I am trying to solve an equation involving a complex argument for the plasma dispersion function as:
$z = x + \iota y$,

$ x = \omega / \sqrt2 k v_{Ti} $

$ y = \nu_i /\sqrt{2} k v_{Ti} $

$S[z] = -\iota  \sqrt{\pi} Exp[-z^2] Erfc[-\iota z]$;

I have reduced the equation to a system of equations corresponding to real part and imaginary part as:

$(x - \beta)(c_1^2 + c_2^2) + \nu_e(d_2c_2 - d_1c_1)=0$,

$\gamma(c_1^2 + c_2^2) + \nu_e(d_2c_1 - d_1c_2)=0$

I am not able to find how should i solve this system for omega and gamma to obtain plots for $\omega$ v/s k and $\gamma$ v/s k? $c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2$ are all functions of S(z). $\beta, \nu_e, \nu_i, v_{Ti}$ are the parameters whose values are known.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you please format your question using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It improves readability and may get more responses. Regards

Comment: That looks a lot better, but there is still no $\omega$ in your reduced equations?

Answer (score 2):

The most simple and usually best way to solve for this is via the Newton-Rhapson Method, which works even for complex variables; so, you do not need to separate the real and imaginary part.

For example, suppose you want to solve for the roots of a complex function $W(x,y)$, given by
$$W(x,y) = -y^2 - x + \frac x{y\sqrt\beta} S(\xi)\,,$$

where $\xi = (x-1)/y \sqrt\beta$, $\beta$ and $y$ are real numbers and $x$ is the complex variable.

Then, for $y=y_0$, we will look for $x=x(y_0)$. Choose $x=z_n$ as an initial seed for the Newton's method.
$$z_{n+1} = -\frac{ W(z_n, y_0) }{ W'(z_n,y_0) }\,,$$

where $W'(x,y) = \partial W/\partial x$. Iterate until $n=N$ where the last equation converges, so that $x(y_0) = z_{N}$.

Now, choose $y=y_1$ and suppose $x=z_n=x(y_0)$ is a good seed. Through the Newton Method you now have $x=x(y_1)$.

Iterate this procedure until some $y_M$.

In the software Mathematica, I have implemented this code:

```
rama[s_,ys_]:=
(
data={};
xn=s;

Table[
    xn=x/.FindRoot[W[x,yn],{x,xn+0. I}];
    AppendTo[data,{yn, Re[xn],Im[xn]}];
    ,{yn,ys,0.02,-0.001}];

Export["data.dat", data]
)
```

You need to choose the first seed $x=s$ and $y=y_s$. Then, the code will find the solutions $x=x(y)$ for $0.02<y<y_s$ in steps of $-0.001$, and the results will be saved in a file with columns $y$ $Re(x)$ $Im(x)$. FindRoot is a function of Mathematica which uses (I hope) the Newton Method.

P.D.: $W(x,y)=0$ represents the dispersion relation of electromagnetic waves propagating along a background magnetic field in a plasma of electrons and protons, where $\beta$ is the beta-parameter, $y$ is the normalized wave-number and $x=x(y)$ is the normalized complex frequency.